# SwiftUI Edit/override all Alerts across the app

Tags: swiftui, alert

I have a lot of Alerts in an app due to specific cases of error handling in many screens, and now I need to display the time on any Alert whenever it shows, **is there a way to edit/override Alert so it includes the time only on debug?**

For example I can achieve this for all prints with:

```
import Foundation

func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n"){
    #if DEBUG
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    Swift.print( df.string(from: Date()) )
    items.forEach{
        Swift.print($0, separator: separator, terminator: terminator)
    }
    #endif
}
```

But how can something like Alert be overriden **without changing every single instance to another element?**

Comment: That kind of depends upon how you are displaying your alerts. I suspect that with that many alerts, you have them centrally managed. If so, you could do it there. If not, you could extend Alert to have another initializer that contains your `Debug` code. You haven't produced a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it is tough to be more specific.

Comment: How are you displaying the alerts? There are different ways to do this, and in iOS 15 `Alert` will be deprecated in future iOS versions. See [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-an-alert)

Comment: @Yrb Sadly I didn't start the app and all Alerts are on the same standard way to display via .alert() on each element, extending alert might be the answer I'm looking for, care to elaborate?

Comment: @George The app still targets and uses iOS 13&14, for iOS 15 a major rework will be needed on the app, so 13&14 is preferable.

Comment: @salvador Sorry I didn't mean it's being deprecated in iOS 15. It's being deprecated in future versions of iOS, not yet released - I accidentally made the mistake when editing the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would **recommend** you just write a function, with a normal name such as `customAlert(...)`. This makes it clearer that it's custom, and also the function has a good naming scheme, unlike calling it `Alert`. `Alert` is ambiguous, and with the exact same parameters, you will get a compiler-time error. Once you have renamed all instances of `Alert` with `customAlert`, you will never have to make this change again.

Example:

```
func customAlert(title: Text, message: Text? = nil, dismissButton: Alert.Button? = nil) -> Alert {
    func alertMessage() -> Text? {
        #if DEBUG
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let date = "Date: \(df.string(from: Date()))"

        if let message = message {
            return Text("\(date)\n\n") + message
        } else {
            return Text(date)
        }
        #else
        return message
        #endif
    }

    return SwiftUI.Alert(title: title, message: alertMessage(), dismissButton: dismissButton)
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Present alert") {
            presentAlert = true
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $presentAlert) {
            customAlert(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the proper answer. Completely agree in keeping names clear, but if someone decides to not rename also make sure to be using Text and make the slight needed changes.

Comment: @salvador Oh yeah, should have left that!

Comment: @salvador The problem is that you get an ambiguous use of `Alert` error... Hmm. The only way is to not name it `Alert`. _I updated my answer_